# working with constructor and accessor method

Tags: java, constructor, accessor

```
package Learning;

public class MatchScore {

    private String MatchNumber;
    private String KillsInMatch;
    private String DeathsInMatch;

    public void setMatchNumber(String nameIn){
        MatchNumber = nameIn;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return MatchNumber ;
    }

    public void setKillsInMatch(String killsIn){
        KillsInMatch = killsIn;
    }
    public String getKillsInMatch(){
        return KillsInMatch;
    }
    public void setDeathsInMatch(String deathsIn){
        DeathsInMatch = deathsIn;
    }
    public String getDeathsinMatch(){
        return DeathsInMatch;
    }

    public void totalStatus(double Stats){
        System.out.printf("This game is %s ", MatchNumber);
        System.out.printf("you killed-this many %s", KillsInMatch);
        System.out.printf("but you died-this many time %s", DeathsInMatch);
    }

}
```

> This ^ is my constructor method. I have created it so that it sets match number, kill number, and death number. These are just variables i have created, then aren't coming from any games or anything.

```
package Learning;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatchScoreS {
    public static void main(String args[])

            throws IOException {
                Scanner diskScanner =
                        new Scanner(new File("MatchScoress.txt")); //the file has to be in the package, in this case the Learning folder.

                for (int games = 1; games <= 5; games++) {
                    checkoutscores(diskScanner);
                        }
                    diskScanner.close();
                        }

            static void checkoutscores(Scanner aScanner) {
                MatchScore aMatch = new MatchScore();
                aMatch.setMatchNumber(aScanner.nextLine());
                aMatch.setKillsInMatch(aScanner.nextLine());
                aMatch.setDeathsInMatch(aScanner.nextLine());
                aScanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

> This ^ would be the accessor method. I have made a file that has the match number, kill number, and death number. I get the error "Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>       at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
>       at Learning.MatchScoreS.checkoutscores(MatchScoreS.java:22)
>       at Learning.MatchScoreS.main(MatchScoreS.java:15)". 
>   When i remove "aScanner.nextLine(); the program doesnt give me an error, but it doesnt bring me the match number and etc.. as well.

I'm just starting to learn java, and im on the chapter with Accessor and constructor methods. any help would be awesome!! Thanks.

Comment: "This ^ is my constructor method." No, that's the whole class - and it doesn't have any declared constructors at all, so you just get the parameterless one that the compiler declares for you by default. But the error you're getting is basically because your file doesn't have enough lines...

Answer (score 0):

you seem a bit confused. you claim an entire class to be an accessor method, and another class to be a constructor method. Accessors are just functions in the class, and so are constructors.

If you have a variable `foo`, accessors for it are usually in the form:

```
void setFoo(<type> value) {
    foo = value
}

<type> getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

hence, in your code, `setMatchNumber()`, `getName()`, `setKillsInMatch()`, `getKillsInMatch()`, etc are accessors (althoug `getName()` should be called `getMatchNumber()`).

A constructor is a method declared with the same name as the class it is contained into, without return type in the declaration. For example, for the `MatchScore` class you may have

```
public MatchScore(String num, String kills, String death) {
    MatchNumber = num;
    KillsInMatch = kills;
    DeathsInMatch = death;
}
```

(btw, usually fields and local variables start non-capitalized, so they should be `matchNumber`, `killsInMatch` and `deathsInMatch` instead).

Now, to your specific exception: it looks like your `Matchscoress.txt` file only has 3 lines, hence the first three `nextLine()` invocations succeed, and the fourth throws an exception.